# How to write text in the World using Turtle Graphics?

Tags: java, turtle-graphics

I am trying to write text in the World window using Turtle Graphics and Java, however I have been reciving a couple different errors (such as the ones below) that are seemingly useless.

```
invalid character constant
```

```
The method write(String) is undefined for the type Turtle
```

My code is pretty short and simple (shown below), so I don't see how anything could get messed up. The final line is the one that

```
import java.util.Scanner; //scanner
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; //dialog boxes


public class ProjectTwo_Ponyville2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

//declare world and turtle
World w = new World(800, 600); //world
Turtle t = new Turtle(w); //turtle

//ask user for name
String strUserName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name");
System.out.println(strUserName);

//print user name in world
t.write('" + strUserName + "');

    }
}
```

Fair warning I'm new to both Turtle Graphics and Java, so it may just be something simple I missed. All the online information I've found about Turtle Graphics uses Python, so nothing's been of much help. Hoping Stack Overflow can solve this for me!

Comment: `strUserName =` -> `String strUserName =`?

Comment: nope! tried it with just normal text and it still doesn't work, but good catch!

Comment: Can you [edit] the post to show your new code and eliminate this first error? Thanks.